# PHP multiple conditional elements within "SELECT * FROM

Tags: php, mysql, select

Currently I am trying to get my head around a conditional code for selecting from a database.

At the moment, I have code that looks at the table and only displays items that are today or after.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
$query_event = "SELECT * FROM campaign WHERE (dateclosed >= '".$today."' || extensiondate >= '".$today."')  AND released = 1  ORDER BY position ASC";
```

This works neatly.

What I want to do, is create a condition on the above code because sometimes there are events that don't necessarily have a close-by date, but I want that to appear in the results as well.

I created an additional field within the `'campaign'` table that I named '`ShowDateRange`'. This being where I can tell an event whether it should have a close-by date. If this field has a '`1`' in it, then it does.

I have read tutes but not too sure how to approach an if else within the call-in. I know this is completely wrong but..

```
$query_event = "SELECT * FROM campaign (if ($ShowDateRange == 1) { WHERE (dateclosed >= '".$today."' || extensiondate >= '".$today."')  AND released = 1 } else { WHERE released = 1 }) ORDER BY position ASC
```

I hope my request for help is not too confusing – Any help or thoughts would be really valued!.

Comment: How about just adding `|| ISNULL(dateclosed)` to the original query?  (assuming your unset values are `null` of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL supports `IF()` conditionals out of the box. Just make sure you get your syntax right as it's slightly different from a PHP `if()`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

also this

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: Perfect that was the exact documentation I was searching for. Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use php statements within mysql. To get around this problem, you should use the result of a mysql statement and use it in the php. So, you can use the following code:

```
if ($ShowDateRange == 1)
{
   $string = "WHERE (dateclosed >= '$today' || extensiondate >= '$today')  AND released = 1";
}
else {
   $string = "WHERE released = 1";
}

$query_event = "SELECT * FROM campaign $string ORDER BY position ASC";
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that solution worked really well and definitely got me on-track with mysql statements. Really appreciate your help.